# Drag and Drop using ListCtrl on wxpython

Tags: python, wxpython

i'm looking for Reset option in drag and drop following the steps i want to know.

1. lst1 i'm dragging to lst2.
2. So there's Reset button which i can set the values by default.
3. Like a original.
   `#DVS chowdary

## Drag and drop GUI

import wx

class MyTarget(wx.TextDropTarget): 
   def **init**(self, object): 
      wx.TextDropTarget.**init**(self) 
      self.object = object

def OnDropText(self, x, y, data): 
      self.object.InsertStringItem(0, data)

class Mywin(wx.Frame):

```
def __init__(self, parent, title): 
    super(Mywin, self).__init__(parent, title = title,size = (-1,300))   
    panel = wx.Panel(self)
    self.index = 0
    box = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)  #horizontal line 
    languages = ['C', 'C++', 'Java', 'Python', 'Perl', 'JavaScript',
     'PHP', 'VB.NET','C#']
    self.lst1 = wx.ListCtrl(panel, -1, style = wx.LC_LIST) 
    self.lst2 = wx.ListCtrl(panel, -1, style = wx.LC_LIST)
    self.display = wx.Button(panel,label="Reset",pos=(10,90))
    #self.but = wx.Button(panel,-1,"Press")
    for lang in languages: 

        self.lst1.InsertStringItem(0,lang)


    #Completed--------
    #self.lst2.InsertStringItem(0,lang)

    dt = MyTarget(self.lst2) 
    self.lst2.SetDropTarget(dt) 
    wx.EVT_LIST_BEGIN_DRAG(self, self.lst1.GetId(), self.OnDragInit)

    dt = MyTarget(self.lst1) 
    self.lst1.SetDropTarget(dt) 
    wx.EVT_LIST_BEGIN_DRAG(self, self.lst2.GetId(), self.OnDragInit1)
    #Completed++++++++++
    self.display.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON,self.onReset)
    box.Add(self.lst1,1,wx.EXPAND) 
    box.Add(self.lst2, 1, wx.EXPAND)
    box.Add(self.display,1,wx.EXPAND) 

    panel.SetSizer(box) 
    panel.Fit() 
    self.Centre() 
    self.Show(True)  

def OnDragInit(self, event):


    text = self.lst1.GetItemText(event.GetIndex())
    tobj = wx.TextDataObject(text) 
    src = wx.DropSource(self.lst1) 
    src.SetData(tobj) 
    src.DoDragDrop(True) 
    self.lst1.DeleteItem(event.GetIndex()) 
def OnDragInit1(self,event):
    text = self.lst2.GetItemText(event.GetIndex()) 
    tobj = wx.TextDataObject(text) 
    src = wx.DropSource(self.lst2) 
    sit = src.SetData(tobj) 
    src.DoDragDrop(True) 
    self.lst2.DeleteItem(event.GetIndex()) 
"""def onReset(self,event):
    languages = ['C', 'C++', 'Java', 'Python', 'Perl', 'JavaScript',
     'PHP', 'VB.NET','C#']
    self.lst1.SetData(languages)
    #print("Hello")

    pass"""
def onReset(self, event):
    """"""
    #||||||||Clearing the values||||||||
    #-----------------------------------
    self.lst1.ClearAll()
    self.lst2.ClearAll()

    languages = ['C', 'C++', 'Java', 'Python', 'Perl', 'JavaScript',
     'PHP', 'VB.NET','C#']
    self.lst1 = wx.ListCtrl(self, -1, style = wx.LC_LIST) 


    #self.but = wx.Button(panel,-1,"Press")
    for lang in languages: 

        self.lst1.InsertStringItem(0,lang)
    """count = self.lst1.GetItemCount()
    for row in range(count):
        item = self.lst1.GetItem( itemIdx=row, col=0)
        print (item.GetText())"""
  #font.SetWeight(wx.FONTWEIGHT_BOLD)
  #  self.lst1.SetItemFont(self.index)
```

ex = wx.App() 
Mywin(None,'Drag&Drop Demo') 
ex.MainLoop()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First allow me to list the issues with your code, other than the `Reset` issue.

Your indentation is a mess, which makes it difficult to understand and therefore many people who could answer your question, simply won't bother.

Make it easy for people to answer your questions.

You appear to be using an extremely old version of `wxPython` or text book, many items are deprecated.

The method of Binding events is historic.

`InsertStringItem` is deprecated.

In `MyTarget(wx.TextDropTarget)` both `init` references should be `__init__`

`MyTarget(wx.TextDropTarget)` should return `True`

`languages` can defined just once.

Finally, use `self.Update` at the end of the `OnReset` to redisplay the lists.

Check the differences between your code and what is below.

```
import wx

class MyTarget(wx.TextDropTarget):
    def __init__(self, object):
        wx.TextDropTarget.__init__(self)
        self.object = object

    def OnDropText(self, x, y, data):
        self.object.InsertItem(0, data)
        return True

class Mywin(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, title):
        super(Mywin, self).__init__(parent, title = title,size = (-1,300))
        panel = wx.Panel(self)
        self.index = 0
        box = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)  #horizontal line
        self.languages = ['C', 'C++', 'Java', 'Python', 'Perl', 'JavaScript',
         'PHP', 'VB.NET','C#']
        self.lst1 = wx.ListCtrl(panel, -1, style = wx.LC_LIST)
        self.lst2 = wx.ListCtrl(panel, -1, style = wx.LC_LIST)
        self.display = wx.Button(panel,label="Reset",pos=(10,90))
        for lang in self.languages:
            self.lst1.InsertItem(0,lang)

        #Completed--------
        #self.lst2.InsertStringItem(0,lang)

        dt = MyTarget(self.lst2)
        self.lst2.SetDropTarget(dt)
        self.lst1.Bind(wx.EVT_LIST_BEGIN_DRAG, self.OnDragInit)

        dt = MyTarget(self.lst1)
        self.lst1.SetDropTarget(dt)
        self.lst2.Bind(wx.EVT_LIST_BEGIN_DRAG, self.OnDragInit1)
        #Completed++++++++++
        self.display.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON,self.onReset)
        box.Add(self.lst1,1,wx.EXPAND)
        box.Add(self.lst2, 1, wx.EXPAND)
        box.Add(self.display,1,wx.EXPAND)

        panel.SetSizer(box)
        panel.Fit()
        self.Centre()
        self.Show(True)

    def OnDragInit(self, event):
        text = self.lst1.GetItemText(event.GetIndex())
        tobj = wx.TextDataObject(text)
        src = wx.DropSource(self.lst1)
        src.SetData(tobj)
        src.DoDragDrop(True)
        self.lst1.DeleteItem(event.GetIndex())

    def OnDragInit1(self,event):
        text = self.lst2.GetItemText(event.GetIndex())
        tobj = wx.TextDataObject(text)
        src = wx.DropSource(self.lst2)
        sit = src.SetData(tobj)
        src.DoDragDrop(True)
        self.lst2.DeleteItem(event.GetIndex())

    def onReset(self, event):
        #||||||||Clearing the values||||||||
        #-----------------------------------
        self.lst1.ClearAll()
        self.lst2.ClearAll()

        for lang in self.languages:
            self.lst1.InsertItem(0,lang)
        self.Update()

ex = wx.App()
Mywin(None,'Drag&Drop Demo')
ex.MainLoop()
```

Comment: Thanks Rolf of Saxony, and apologizes for inconvenient.